# Is there have a Chooser or Launcher to start screen rotation settings after Windows Phone 8 Update 3?

Tags: windows-phone-8

There is an app called ‘Auto Rotate Screen’ in Windows Phone Store, it can start screen rotation settings, how is it achieved?

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/auto-rotate-screen/956f2246-fb85-43c4-a48c-bcc7bc8e484b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a Luncher to do this.

The URI scheme is: `"ms-settings-screenrotation:"`.

To lunch it just write:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-screenrotation:"));
```

To avoid errors, check if update 3 for Windows Phone 8 is on the device first:

```
private static Version TargetedVersion = new Version(8, 0, 10492);
public static bool IsTargetedVersion
{
    get { return Environment.OSVersion.Version >= TargetedVersion; }
}
```

[(Source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)